# Convert character date and time with milliseconds to numeric in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, numeric, milliseconds

I have the following Timestamp vector:

```
Timestamp <- c("30-09-2016 11:45:00.000", "01-10-2016 06:19:57.860", "01-10-2016 06:20:46.393")
```

Timestamp is part of a table (unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a data.frame...) that contains other columns of degrees and weight:

```
  Timestamp Weight Degrees
1 30-09-2016 11:45:00.000 38.19 40.00 
2 01-10-2016 06:19:57.860 39.12 40.00 
3 01-10-2016 06:20:46.393 42.11 41.00
```

I would like to plot Weight against Timestamp, but the mode of Timestamp is "character", which means that the x-axis is not read properly. Would you have any suggestion to convert this to numeric?

I have tried `as.Date(Timestamp,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS3')` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @J_F Need to use `as.POSIXct` rather than `as.Date` to preserve time information.

Answer (score 6):

As Erdem said, with `as.POSIXct` with `%OS` for seconds

```
t1 <- c("30-09-2016 11:45:00.000", "01-10-2016 06:19:57.860", "01-10-2016 06:20:46.393")     
t2 <- as.POSIXct(t1,format = "%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%OS")
```

note that timestamps are displayed/printed in whole seconds by default; see `digits.secs` in `?options`

```
t2
 [1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00 EDT" "2016-10-01 06:19:57 EDT" "2016-10-01 06:20:46 EDT"
```

but millisecond resolution is maintained internally

```
diff(t2)
 Time differences in secs
 [1] 66897.860    48.533
```

if you want to display/print millisecond resolution set by using

```
options(digits.secs=3)
t2
 [1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00.000 EDT" "2016-10-01 06:19:57.859 EDT" "2016-10-01 06:20:46.392 EDT"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(Timestamp,format = "%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%OS")
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I do what you suggest the milliseconds are cut out, so i only get                                                                                                > y <- as.POSIXct(Timestamp,format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%OS")
> y
[1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00 CEST" "2016-10-01 06:19:57 CEST" "2016-10-01 06:20:46 CEST"

Comment: there may be two things happening here; 1) I think format for seconds should be %OS instead of %S.%OS and 2) the printed value is rounded according to options(digits.secs)