# how to match quote and trade data with data.table (rolling join)

Tags: r, data.table

I am desperately trying to reproduce the classical `Pandas` example of rolling joins, where `quotes` data is merged with `trade` data.

See here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Here is the data in `data.table` format:

```
trades <- data.table(time = c('2016-05-25 13:30:00.023',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.038',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.048',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.048',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.048'),
                     ticker = c('MSFT','MSFT','GOOG','GOOG','AAPL'),
                     price = c(51.95,51.95,720.77,720.92,98.0),
                     quantity = c(75,155,100,100,100))
> trades
                      time ticker  price quantity
1: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT  51.95       75
2: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT  51.95      155
3: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.77      100
4: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.92      100
5: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL  98.00      100
```

and quotes

```
quotes <- data.table(time = c('2016-05-25 13:30:00.023',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.023',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.030',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.041',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.048',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.049',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.072',
                              '2016-05-25 13:30:00.075'),
                     ticker = c('GOOG','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','GOOG','AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'),
                     bid = c(720.50, 51.95, 51.97, 51.99, 720.5,97.99,720.5,52.01),
                     ask = c(270.93,51.96,51.98,52.00,720.93,98.01,720.88,52.03))
> quotes
                      time ticker    bid    ask
1: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   GOOG 720.50 270.93
2: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT  51.95  51.96
3: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.030   MSFT  51.97  51.98
4: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.041   MSFT  51.99  52.00
5: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.50 720.93
6: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.049   AAPL  97.99  98.01
7: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.072   GOOG 720.50 720.88
8: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.075   MSFT  52.01  52.03
```

What I would like to do is merge the trades data with the quotes data in the following way

1. for each trade, match the closest **previous** quote possible
2. the matched quote must be within 10 millisecond
3. exact matches should **not** occur.

The output (which is the same as in the Pandas tutorial) should be

```
                      time ticker  price quantity   bid   ask
1: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT  51.95       75    NA    NA
2: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT  51.95      155 51.97 51.98
3: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.77      100    NA    NA
4: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.92      100    NA    NA
5: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL  98.00      100    NA    NA
```

Indeed, you can see that the only possible quote match is for the second trade at `2016-05-25 13:30:00.038`, because the closed (previous) quote occurs at `2016-05-25 13:30:00.030` so this is within 10ms (and not an exact match).

Despite my trials, I was not able to reproduce this in `data.table`. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also combine [this idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313203/5793905) with a rolling join,
which is similar but not quite equal to what @sindri_baldur proposed:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

quotes[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")]
trades[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")]

match_inexact <- function(q_time, t_time, bid, ask) {
  exact <- q_time == t_time # exact matches get NA
  bid[exact] <- NA_real_
  ask[exact] <- NA_real_
  list(bid, ask)
}

trades[, c("bid", "ask") := quotes[.SD,
                                   match_inexact(x.time, i.time, x.bid, x.ask),
                                   on = .(ticker, time),
                                   roll = lubridate::dmilliseconds(10L)]]
```

An important thing to note:
`time` is the last column specified for the join because that's the column where `data.table` will try to roll values.

Comment: wow pretty good. Do you mind explaning a little bit more whats going on?

Comment: In this case the rolling join notation (active when you specify `roll`) means: for the last column used to join, look behind by at most 10ms if there's no exact match. With `match_inexact` we can simply check whether the times were rolled or not: if `x.time == i.time`, no roll was done, it was an exact match. The idiom just assigns the resulting columns (each packed in a list) to `trades` by reference.

Comment: ok got it. but one point, what does the i.time refers to? the time variable in the left DT?

Comment: Ah, in the `data.table` documentation they usually describe things with variables `x[i, j, by]`, where `i` can be another `data.table`. During the join, they expose the variables with `x.` and `i.` prefixes, depending on which table the value was taken from. So `i.time` is from `.SD`, which represents the subset of data coming from `trades`.

Comment: got it. and I guess x. refers to the left DT? in this case `trades`?

Comment: `x.` does refer to the left, but the actual join is nested and specified as `quotes[.SD, ...`, so it would refer to `quotes`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is something (quick and dirty) that gets the job done:

```
# Format as POSIXct*
quotes[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")]
trades[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")]

# Match the nearest time (in the right direction) for each ticker and add as column
trades[quotes, on = .(time > time, ticker), qtime := i.time]
# Remove if not within time limit (10 millsecs)
trades[(time - qtime) > 0.01, qtime := NA_real_]
# Now perform an equi-join after removing timestamp that was too distant
trades[, c("bid", "ask") := quotes[trades, on = .(time = qtime), .(bid, ask)]]
trades[, !"qtime"] # drop this temporary column

#                   time ticker  price quantity   bid   ask
# 1: 2016-05-25 13:30:00   MSFT  51.95       75    NA    NA
# 2: 2016-05-25 13:30:00   MSFT  51.95      155 51.97 51.98
# 3: 2016-05-25 13:30:00   GOOG 720.77      100    NA    NA
# 4: 2016-05-25 13:30:00   GOOG 720.92      100    NA    NA
# 5: 2016-05-25 13:30:00   AAPL  98.00      100    NA    NA
```

*  POSIXct vectors are built
on top of double vectors, where the value represents the number of seconds since 1970-01-01

Learning from Alexis' post here is a slightly cleaner version that uses the roll argument.

```
trades[, c("qtime", "bid", "ask") := quotes[.SD, roll = 0.01, on = .(ticker, time), .(x.time, bid, ask)]]
trades[time == qtime, c("bid", "ask") := NA_real_][, qtime := NULL]
```

Comment: interesting. thanks! could you please explain what you do there? what does the `qtime := i.time` do? why cant we just do it in one pass with some `roll` arguments? thanks!

Comment: Will try to add some more comments. Maybe there is a way to do it with one roll argument. I am a beginner with non-equi joins.

Comment: same idea here. `time > time` is a bit ambiguous. how can I make sure I am referring to `time` of `quotes` or `time` of `trades`?

Comment: Agree. But in this case the first time refers to `trades`. Anyway I would go with the second *cleaner* version.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible non-equi join approach using the latest quote within that 10ms window:

```
options(digits.secs=3) #see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475068/1989480
library(data.table)

quotes[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")]
trades[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")][,
    c("start", "end") := .(time-0.01, time)]

trades[, c("bid", "ask") :=
        quotes[trades, on=.(ticker, time>=start, time<end), mult="last", .(bid, ask)]
    ][, c("start", "end") := NULL]
```

output:

```
                      time ticker  price quantity   bid   ask
1: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT  51.95       75    NA    NA
2: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT  51.95      155 51.97 51.98
3: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.77      100    NA    NA
4: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG 720.92      100    NA    NA
5: 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL  98.00      100    NA    NA
```

Comment: cool stuff. do you mind just explaining what you do here? what is the `mult` argument?

Comment: `mult` arg allows you to handle cases with one-to-many matches (when `mult="last"` use last observation, see `?data.table` for more details). i think the join condition is clear?

Comment: cool thanks! and assuming I wanted the first quote AFTER the trade (and within 10ms) all I need is switch time <= start, right?

Comment: iiuc, i think its `trades[, c("after_start","after_end") := .(time, time+0.01)]; ......[, time>after_start, time<=after_end` if u use `tradetime` instead of just `time` it will help with your understanding

Comment: yes, this is a bit confusing. In `on=.(ticker, time>=start, time<end)` there `time` variable is actually present in both the `quotes` and `trades` data. how to make sure there is no ambiguitiy? using the `i.` syntax?

Comment: Imo, best to dupe the columns before the join

Comment: you mean by giving them another name before the merge?

Comment: Something like DT[,colToBeUsedInJoin:=existingColumnsWithCalcIfNecessary]