# Is there any way of preserving the hundredths of seconds with the function "as.ITime" of data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, data-conversion, duration

I'd like to transform a column of a table of class "**data.table**" which is in characters ("01:22:03.56" for example) into date format with the [data.table] function "**as.ITime**", but I lose the **hundredths of seconds** after conversion (01:22:03). Is there any way of preserving the hundredths of seconds with [data.table]?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/43471386/680068

Comment: I don't think you can get milliseconds using ITime, as it stores seconds as integer. See linked post, convert to as.POSIXct

Comment: Backing up zx8754's comment: in `?as.ITime`, it starts by saying *"Date and time classes with integer storage"*, which can be verified with `dput(as.ITime("01:22:03.56"))`. The `POSIXt` recommendation is likely the most-direct route, though you will need to pick a date to prepend to the time, since `POSIXt` is a date/timestamp, not just a time (or period), though if you're adding to it, you'll need to consider modulo math. Alternatively, you can try `lubridate::hms` to create a "period", not sure if that works for all that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front: `ITime` by-design stores as an integer. From `?as.ITime`:

```
Description:

     Date and time classes with integer storage for fast sorting and
     grouping. Still experimental!
```

This means there is no direct way of storing the time with milliseconds using `as.ITime`.

Options, which is best depends heavily on what your follow-on processing requires.

1. Use `lubridate::hms`, which creates an object of class `"Period"`.

   ```r
   tm <- lubridate::hms("01:22:03.56")
   tm + 5
   # [1] "1H 22M 8.56S"
   ### this will look odd ...
   tm - 5
   # [1] "1H 22M -1.44S"
   ### ... but it works out in the end
   (tm + 5) - (tm - 5)
   # [1] "10S"
   ```
2. Pick a date (arbitrary) and prepend it to the time, then use `as.POSIXct`:

   ```r
   tm <- as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", "01:22:03.56"))
   tm
   # [1] "1970-01-01 01:22:03 EST"
   ### to prove that milliseconds are in there, you can either
   dput(tm)
   # structure(22923.56, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
   ### or you can set how it is rendered on the console
   options(digits.secs=3)
   tm
   # [1] "1970-01-01 01:22:03.56 EST"
   tm + 5
   # [1] "1970-01-01 01:22:08.56 EST"
   tm - 5
   # [1] "1970-01-01 01:21:58.56 EST"
   ```
3. If all you need is a numeric interpretation of that time, then

   ```r
   time2num <- function(x) {
     vapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y) * c(60*60, 60, 1)),
            numeric(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
   }
   tm <- time2num("01:22:03.56")
   tm
   # [1] 4923.56
   ```

Comment: excellent answer, thank you. My aim is to be able to make statistics on sports competition times, avoiding false ties in terms of rank due to the removal of hundredths of a second.